# Code coverage tool for CuTest

Tags: c, unit-tests

I am using [CuTest](http://cutest.sourceforge.net/) to do Unit testing for my project. We chose this framework as it is a light weight. how to check the code coverage using CuTest. I have a experience in using Bull eye code coverage tool. Is there any open source coverage tool like bulls eye code coverage.